# changing winform properties for different clients

Tags: winforms

I have a winforms app and want to customize for differents clients, I need a simple mechanism to create a version for client1 with one commandline app for example. I only want to change the color of the window and of buttons and a smart logo. I dont want to change it manually every time I need a client1 version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put in your app.config some configuration tags, some properties you need. And then let's say, through your setup process, you modify the configuration based on client desires( that's if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of app you have but I had an app that is accessible for 3 different types of users which are admin, receptionist and patient. I used password authentication and inside the forms, I used simple `if/else` clauses according to authentication types to arrange which user could use which parts of the app. But as far as I understand you need something like an interface in case any other client takes part in the app later.